# Disable client- or proxy-side caching on anonymous pages (Cache-Control header), without disabling server-side caching?

Tags: caching

My CDN seems to cache the /user page, which means I can't access my account page after logging in. I could add it to cacheexclude's uncached list, but that would make PHP run for every bot that hits my server.

What could I do so that Drupal serves the /user page with "Cache-Control: no-cache", or something targeted at proxies (CDN), for anonymous users?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using `context` and [`context_http_headers`](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_http_headers) (`7.x-1.x`) to add custom `Cache-Control:` headers on the user page.